# Looking for QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS "Summarize"

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, statistics, summarizing

In ArcMap, the user can create a table that groups the field values using summarize field tool (as shown below)

[image]

How can I create a table that summarizes field values in QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the plugin: ["Dissolve with Stats"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DissolveWithStats/), which can be installed from the plugin manager.

After starting the plugin from the Vector menu, you chose which layer to dissolve, which field in the attribute table to dissolve by, then which other attributes to aggregate: either count for any type of field or summarize, min, max etc for numeric fields.

The result gets saved to a new shapefile.

Comment: Can you expand more on your answer and provide more content?

Comment: Many Thanks Micha, I tried it and it worked fine. 
Is there any tool/plugin that extracts the summary to table instead of SHP?

Comment: Just save the shapefile attribute table to a CSV.

Comment: IS the "Dissolve with Stats" plugin still available in QGIS 3.0?

Answer (score 14):

QGIS has a Statistics Panel that allows you to view a long list of descriptive statistics for whichever vector layer you choose. To open the statistical summary tool, either click `View -> Statistical Summary` OR `View -> Panels -> Statistics Panel`, Or you can use this icon on the toolbar [image] and you will get statistical description for any vector layer but only for fields with numerical types like real, integer, and long integer types. It will not work for fields of type text (string).

This an example of land use vector data:

[image]

Comment: I think this one should be marked as the correct answer?  Its the most straightforward approach and most similar to the summarize function in Arc.

Comment: No; although useful this appears to be the counterpart to ArcGIS "Statistics" function, not ArcGIS "Summarize" which is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 7):

QGIS 3.14 does this with the ["Statistics by Categories"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#statistics-by-categories) tool under Vector Analysis in the QGIS's Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This should be the actual answer. As Sideshow Bob said, the QGIS "Statistics Panel" apparently does the same as right clicking on a field in ArcGIS and clicking "Statistics". What we're looking for is the equivalent of ArcGIS "Summarize". For example, I wanted to find the frequency of each value in a field. In ArcGIS to do this I would right click on a field header and then choose "Summarize". I accomplished this in QGIS using the "Statistics by categories" tool shown here. Maybe "Dissolve with Stats" is also a solution, but this is better because it uses a built in tool, not a plugin.

Answer (score 3):

The more similar tool is the ["Group Stats"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/) plugin.