# Statistical summary of points in a polygon (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, point, statistics

Is there any method for calculating the average, largest value, etc. (chosen statistic value) of points within polygons and giving the calculated value to the polygon?
[image]

Comment: It would be very helpful if you included the software you're working with in your question and tags.

Comment: Ah, sorry! It's QGIS

Comment: This question may have some useful suggestions (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266303/looking-for-qgis-equivalent-of-arcgis-summarize), although you might need to do a spatial join/intersect too. You're looking for the QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS's Summarize Within tool (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/analysis/summarize-within.htm).